# Inference for Spearman's Correlation

Tags: inference, spearman-rho, importance, ranks

Assume a set of variables $x_1,...,x_p$ and their variable importance indices given by two different predictive models. Regardless of the importance metric itself (as long as we use the same metric for both models), I want to look at the ranking of their importance: which variable is the most important for model A, second most important for A,  which is the most important for model B and so on.

So now for each model I have a different permutation of the rank vector $(1,...,p)$, denoted $r^A,r^B$ and I want to test whether these rankings are correlated. My null hypothesis would be something like "the vectors $r^A,r^B$ are not correlated" (I relate here only to positive correlation).

The proper way of handling rank vectors (all distinct integers, no ties) is probably using Spearman's correlation coefficient:

$$r_s=1-\frac{6\sum_i{d_i^2}}{p^3-p},\quad d_i=r_i^A-r_i^B$$

So a convenient formulation for the null hypothesis would be something like $H_0:r_s\le 0.4$. But, we don't really have a convenient distribution for Spearman's. So the way to go is transformations. I've got two possible transformations:

1. [Kruskal's transformation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2281954) from Spearman's $r_s$ to Pearson's $\rho$:
   $$\rho=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}r_s\right)$$
2. [Fisher's $z$-transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) from Pearson's $\rho$ to normal:
   $$z'=\tanh^{-1}(\rho),\quad z'\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{1}{p-3}\right)$$

I've seen some examples where the $z$ transformation is applied directly on $r_s$, and I'm not feeling like it's the right thing to do. However, Kruskal himself (and citing papers) require a bivariate normal distribution, which I'm not sure I can fulfill.

Any thoughts?

Comment: But $r_s$ is not a population parameter, it is calculated based on the sample. So how can you 'test' something like $H_0:r_s\le 0.4$?

Comment: Agreed, it ain't a population parameter but rather a measure of rank agreement

Comment: Before you think about statistical tests or even about any statistics at all, you need to clarify your stochastic model. As stated, you have an input dataset, two models and the respective VI measure. That's it, everything is determined and there is no randomness. It sounds more as if you are looking for a convenient distance/similarity measure between the two rankings.  So I suggest: 1) You clarify the source of randomness 2) Decide a similarity measure 3) Determine the distribution of 2) und 1) and finally 4) determine a suitable test based on 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: You mentioned you have permutations of rank vectors. Can you use a permutation test for the hypothesis test?

Comment: A permutation test would not fit my needs here